# Prove/Disprove that $X$ is compact

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, compactness

Suppose that $f: X \to Y$ is an injective function, where $Y$ has some topology $T_Y$. Equip $X$ with the topology $T_X :=\{f^{-1}(U):U\in T_Y\}$. Suppose that $Y$ is Hausdorff and compact.

I was wondering whether we can infer that $X$ is compact. I found out that $X$ is not necessarily compact, but I noticed that if $f(X)$ is closed, then $X$ is compact. I'm not sure of my work especially in the second one, so I want some critique. Thanks.

$1)$  Consider $X = [0,1[$, $Y = [0,1]$ and $f: X\to Y$, $f(x) = x$. Let $T_Y$ be the topology on $Y$ inherited from the usual topology on $\Bbb R$, $\tau$ be the topology on $X$ inherited from the usual topology on $\Bbb R$ and let's show that $\tau = T_X$. Let $a$ denote the usual topology on $\Bbb R$.

If $O \in \tau$, then $O = O' \cap [0,1[$ where $O' \in a$. Then $O'':=O'\setminus\{1\} \in a$ and $O = O'' \cap [0,1] \in T_Y$, hence $f^{-1}(O) \in T_X$, but $f^{-1}(O) = O$, so $O \in T_X$.

If $O \in T_X$, $O = f^{-1}(U)$, where $U \in T_Y$, so $U = U' \cap [0,1]$ where $U'\in a$. Then $$f^{-1}(U) = f^{-1}(U) \cap X = f^{-1}(U) \cap f^{-1}([0,1[) \\ = f^{-1}(U \cap [0,1[) = f^{-1}(U\setminus \{1\}) = f^{-1}(U' \cap [0,1[) = U' \cap [0,1[$$

So $O \in \tau$ and this proves $\tau = T_X$.

So in this example, $Y$ is Hausdorff and compact, $f$ is injective, but $X$ is not compact.

$2)$ Suppose that $f(X)$ is closed. Note that since $f$ is injective, $X$ is Hausdorff. We have $f:X \to f(X)$ is bijective. Let $g$ denote its inverse. We have $f(X)$ is compact since $Y$ is compact and $f(X)$ is closed. Now we claim that $(X,T_X) \cong (f(X), T_Y(f(X)))$, where $T_Y(f(X))$ is the topology on $f(X)$ inherited from $T_Y$. This will imply that $X$ is compact.

Proof: let's show that $g:(f(X),T_Y(f(X))) \to (X,T_X)$ is continuous. If $V \in T_X$, say $V = f^{-1}(U)$ where $U\in T_Y$, then: $g^{-1}(V) = g^{-1}(V) \cap f(X) = U \cap f(X) $, so $g^{-1}(V) \in T_Y(f(X))$ and $g$ is continuous. Now since $(f(X),T_Y(f(X)))$ is compact and $(X,T_X)$ is Hausdorff, we get that $g$ is a homeomorphism and the conclusion follows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s correct, but it could be shortened a bit. In your counterexample you could note directly that $T_X$ is the relative topology that $X$ inherits from $Y$, and since $Y$ has the relative topology that it inherits from $\Bbb R$, $T_X$ must be $\tau$. In your proof of the general result when $f[X]$ is closed you don’t actually have to note that $g$ is a homeomorphism, though there’s certainly no harm in doing so: continuous maps preserve compactness, so continuity of $g$ is sufficient.

In fact you could observe more generally that if $Z=f[X]$, then $f$ is a homeomorphism between $X$ and $Z$: it’s a continuous, open bijection. Since $Y$ is compact Hausdorff, $Z$ (and hence also $X$) is compact if and only if $Z$ is closed in $Y$.

Comment: Thank you for your quick feedback and comments! By the way, do you think it is likely the case that there is a trivial counterexample to the first one?

Comment: @François: Your’e welcome! Perhaps the simplest counterexample is to let $X=\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$ and $Y=\{0\}\cup X$. Give $Y$ it’s usual topology, and $X$ will get its usual (discrete) topology. Take $f(x)=x$ for $x\in X$, as you did. This strips the example to its essentials.

Comment: Brian, how do you think of counter examples this fast? you are way too fast... I wish I was that fast

Comment: @ILoveMath: I’ve been doing it for *long* time: I had an excellent topology course about 50 years ago my first year in college and specialized in it in grad school.

Comment: If you dont mind asking, what book of topology did u use and would u recommend us to be as good as you in topology? or at least to be knowloeadgable about topology

Comment: @ILoveMath: My first course was from John Greever, who used a pre-publication version of the [textbook](https://www.amazon.com/Theory-Examples-Point-set-Topology-Greever/dp/B000E7S2UE). It’s a modified [Moore method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_method) text: The most complicated results and examples are dealt with in detail, but most of the results are merely stated, the proofs being left to the students in lieu of exercises. It has all of the basic general topological material, though I seem to recall that it’s a bit weaker on metric spaces. I loved it, but it’s not a good text ...

Comment: ... for self-study unless one has easy access to someone who can check one’s work. I’m not familiar with most of the current crop of topology texts. The one by Munkres has very good overall coverage, and though there are things about it that I really don’t like, it is generally quite clear and well written. At a more advanced level I like Willard, *General Topology*. I will also tentatively recommend one book that I’ve never seen, [*Topology*](https://www.amazon.com/Topology-Sheldon-W-Davis/dp/0071243399) by Sheldon Davis. I used to know Sheldon, and I know his background, so I suspect ...

Comment: ... that it’s a decent relatively modern treatment. But as I say, I’ve never actually seen the book.